# How to extract dates with datatye DATETIME from colum A in table X and put them into Table Y while changing datatype into DATE

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime, extract

Long title, easy meaning:
How is it possible to extract from a date like "2014-04-04 10:47:30.000", which is stored in one column, it's components like year, month and day?
I'm not interested in the time.

For example, I have a table called "Incidents". Inside the table we got a column called "IncidentID" and a column called "ReportingDate", in which dates like the above-mentionend are stored. Let's say we have about 50k Incidents, therefore we have also 50k dates.
A year has 365 days. I want to query for the count of the Incidents, which were reported on different dates - for instance on the 5th of October 2013.

So: How can I get the components of the date and put them into another table while having own columns for the components and how can I query for the Incidents as well?

I guess at first I have to change the datatype of the date from DATETIME to DATE, but I'm not quite sure how to go further. May anyone help me while giving me a code and explains me what it does for a sql-noob? :-)

Comment: `cast(datetimecolumn as date)`

Comment: @Laurence that works, but: (a) In almost all cases, you want to avoid performing expressions against the columns, since it can thwart SQL Server's ability to use an index effectively. (b) While cast as date can be an exception to that rule in current versions of SQL Server, that doesn't mean it will always work that way, not does it mean it's great; see [this answer by Martin Smith](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/34052/1186). The proper way is to use a range query, like in [Hamlet's answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19645608/61305).

Comment: @AaronBertrand You're right, I didn't read the full question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this

> I want to query for the count of the Incidents, which were reported on
>   different dates - for instance on the 5th of October 2013.

you haven't do this:

> I guess at first I have to change the datatype of the date from
>   DATETIME to DATE, but I'm not quite sure how to go further.

Just query

```
SELECT
  IncidentID
FROM incidents
WHERE ReportingDate >= '20131005'
    AND ReportingDate < '20131006'
```

Comment: Interesting - didn't knew that, but of course it makes sence. Thanks at all for your answer. If there is something not quite clear to me, I'll come back. :-)